# Multidimensional Array C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to print a board from user input (on command line) which suppose to print something like this

[image: board]

if I print without line number 23 i.e (`board[i][j] = i, j;`) my result is something like this.

[image: board2]

and if I add the above mentioned line, the compiler is giving me an error:

> expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM_MAX 9

int d;
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];

int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
    d = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {     
            board[i][j] = i, j;
            printf(" %i ", board[i][j]);                     
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `i, j` is an abuse of the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). It's not clear what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I am trying to assign values to the arrays so I can print them (which I think is wrong) that's why I need help.

Comment: @user3386109 That's technically not an abuse of the comma operator, since that's a completely well formed statement.  I'd agree that the use of i and the comma are redundant, but it is completely well defined by the language standard what the result will be.

Comment: @dgnuff Agreed that it is completely well defined, as being completely useless. Hence, it's an abuse. You say "təˈmātō", I say "təˈmätō".

Comment: @iffitheking You can use another variable, initialized to `d*d-1` to keep track of the value that you want to write to the array.

Comment: @user3386109 can you tell me more about `d*d-1` I don't get it, please.

Comment: @iffitheking After the `atoi`, add the line `int value=d*d-1`. And change the `i,j` to `value`. See what you get, and see if you can figure it out from there.

Comment: @user3386109 ahh great it somewhat solved the problem, it only printed 8s well I will try to solve from here, and will get back to you, thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
board[i][j] = i, j;
```

is indeed your problem.  To see why, look up the comma operator in C. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

You do need to use both `i` and `j` on the right of the `=` on that line, but not as you are currently doing.